# Compare 2 fields of table A with 6 fields of table B

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables in my MySQL DB. One contains `requiredSkill1`, `requiredSkillLevel1`, `requiredSkill2`, `requiredSkillLevel2`, `requiredSkill3` and `requiredSkillLevel3`.

The other table has X rows per user with the following collumns: `skill` and `level`.

```
itemid  requiredSkill1  requiredSkillLevel1 requiredSkill2  requiredSkillLevel2 requiredSkill3  requiredSkillLevel3
2410    3319            4                   20211           1                   NULL            NULL
```

The other table:

```
userid  skill   level
21058   3412    4
21058   3435    2
21058   3312    4
```

Keep in mind, these are just examples.

I want every `itemid` which has matching values in `requiredSkill{1-3}` and `requiredSkillLevel{1-3}`.

Is this even possible with a single query and is this still performant, since the user table contains up to 300 rows per user and the item table has a fixed value of 6000 rows. This will be used in a web application, so I can use Ajax to load ranges of items from the database to decrease loading time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the data set up.  A [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be helpful, but I think you want to approach it like this:

```
  SELECT itemid FROM items i
  INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.skill = i.requiredSkill1 AND u1.level >= i.requiredSkillLevel1
  INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.skill = i.requiredSkill2 AND u2.level >= i.requiredSkillLevel2 AND u1.userid = u2.userid
  INNER JOIN users u3 ON u3.skill = i.requiredSkill3 AND u3.level >= i.requiredSkillLevel3 AND u3.userid = u1.userid
```

Someone will solve this for you if you post demo data.